# Cannot access read-only document .xlsx

Tags: excel, vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagrtidview.
I created a button "Export datagridview to Excel"

Below is the code for the export:

```
 Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value


    xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("C:\Masterlist.xlsx")
    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()

    releaseObject(xlApp)
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)

    MsgBox("You can find the file in C:\Masterlist.xlsx")
End Sub
```

**I have also included reference: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel**

However when I finished my project as an application, I install my application on other computer and this happens when I click on "Export to Excel" button:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F45Q5.png

What code that can disable read-only?
Or any code here that makes this error appears?

Thanks!

Comment: Is Excel installed on the 'other computer'? Does an error occur when run it on any other computer that **does** have excel installed?

Comment: The error refers to the workbook "Masterlist" which you create in your code, meaning you have full control over the parameters with which it is created. There is no need for it to be ReadOnly. In fact, I don't see that it is that. However, after this workbook is created, the only attempt to access it is in xlWorkBook.Close(). I wonder whether the empty brackets are causing the error. The Close method shouldn't need them in VBA.

Comment: Yes the error still occured even on any other computer (with Excel been installed) @Jeeped

Comment: I tried to remove the () but it won't allow me. It stays there whenver i tried to delete @Variatus

Comment: Instead of exporting from DataGridView to Excel, why not import the file created by DataGridView into Excell using Excel's own VBA?

Comment: I am guessing this is a permissions issue. The error indicates three (3) possibilities. The file name or path does not exist; another program is using the file; the workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook. If the file created is new, as the code appears to do and it does not exist in the destination path, then none of the indicated errors appears to be the real problem. I moved the path to a folder where permission(s) are granted and it saved properly. Have you tried a different path?

Comment: I have tried different path. I change to D:\ but error. This problem ocurrs when I run my application on other computer. It works fine when I run my application in my computer @JohnG

Comment: I am aware that this happens when you run it on another computer. I guess my point is that the read-only error cannot possibly be coming from YOUR code as you are trying to save a new file. In addition, if the file was actually saved to the destination and then had a read only problem when opening the file then you could look at your code, but this is not happening. The file is NOT being saved read-only or any other format.

Comment: That is what signals there must be a permission problem writing to the path. I have full permission on my machine but the code will still throw this error when I try to save to C: drive. If I switch the path to the desktop, there is no problem.  Have you tried to set the path to the desktop, as most users’ desktops are valid places to save files? Example: `Dim desktopPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\Masterlist.xlsx"`

Comment: How to change the path to desktop? I've tried your code above but it gives error @JohnG

Comment: What error are you getting? I copy pasted from working code.

Comment: Where suppose this code dim desktopPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\Masterlist.xlsx" placed in my code actually? @JohnG

Comment: That line defines a string called `desktopPath`. It is the path to the desktop and "Masterlist.xlsx". Put that line above the `SaveAs` Line then change the `SaveAs` line to:  `xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(desktopPath)`

Comment: It works. But the excel file is empty. Nothing in datagridview is exported to that Excel worksheet. @JohnG

Comment: Hmm. The posted code does not show anything related to the `DataGridView`. That sound like another question. Loop through the rows of `DataGridView` and copy the cells to Excel. There are many example of this if you search for them. Try something to get the `DataGridView` cells into the excel worksheet. You already have the workbook open, maybe a loop through all the rows in the datagridview before you close the excel file. At least you will know that the file will save properly.  Try something.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out but how to loop through? I dont have any idea of this because I am new to this. @JohnG

Comment: Google is your friend. The search for “C# Loop through DataGridView cells” turned up 17,000+ results. The first one looks promising. [Looping through DataGridView Cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788156/looping-through-datagridview-cells). Try it.